# how to add dynamic value to simple star plugin with jquery

Tags: jquery, rating

I would like to give dynamic number to [Simple Star Rating Plugin](http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Simple-Star-Rating-Plugin-with-jQuery-Font-Awesome-Raterater.html), when I try to add dynamically from javascript its not working. Please find my below code, not sure what I'm doing wrong here: Can someone help why my dynamic div is not showing up in html, if I put alert statement I'm getting proper div element tag, but for some reason its not appending to html tag

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Raterater Demo</title>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/css/rating/raterater.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<style>
/* Override star colors */
.raterater-bg-layer {
    color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.25 );
}
.raterater-hover-layer {
    color: rgba( 255, 255, 0, 0.75 );
}
.raterater-hover-layer.rated {
    color: rgba( 255, 255, 0, 1 );
}
.raterater-rating-layer {
    color: rgba( 255, 155, 0, 0.75 );
}
.raterater-outline-layer {
    color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.25 );
}
</style>
<script>
    function loadstar() {
        var rate1= document.createElement('div');
        var starid=0;
        var starrating=3.8;
        rate1.innerHTML = "<div class='ratebox' data-id="+starid+" data-rating="+ starrating+"></div>";
        document.getElementById('rating111').appendChild(rate1);
        $("#rating111").append(rate1.innerHTML);
        alert( "div value" + rate1.innerHTML);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="loadstar()">
<!-- Lets add some rating boxes
<div class="ratebox" data-id="2" data-rating="3.5"></div>
 -->
<div id="rating111">
</div>
<!-- We need jquery and raterater.jquery.js -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/rating/raterater.jquery.js"></script>

<script>
/* This is out callback function for when a rating is submitted
 */
function rateAlert(id, rating)
{
    alert( 'Rating for '+id+' is '+rating+' stars!' );
}

/* Here we initialize raterater on our rating boxes
 */
$(function() {
    $( '.ratebox' ).raterater( {
        submitFunction: 'rateAlert',
        allowChange: true,
        starWidth: 100,
        spaceWidth: 10,
        numStars: 5
    } );
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```